# Replace placeholder value with innerHTML of span tag clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, innerhtml

I would like to have a hidden search form on my page to allow users to filter tags onclick. I think I started out on the right track, but I may have fallen down the rabbit hole.

As of now I can replace the value in the form, but I don't know how to run the loop so that it only returns the innerHTML of the item that is clicked. It currently runs through all of the options and stops at the last.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is what I have for the tags:

```
<div id="tagLinks" class="tags" >
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Social Media</span>,   
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Business</span>, 
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Content</span>, 
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Marketing</span>, 
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Engagement</span>, 
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Facebook</span>, 
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Twitter</span>, 
    <span class="clickable" onclick="getValue();">Google Plus</span>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript: 
        $(document).ready(function() {

```
    var tagArray = document.getElementById("tagLinks").innerText.split(', ');
    var spanObj; 
    tagArray.forEach(createElement);

    function createElement(arrayItem, index, array) {
        spanObj = "<span class='clickable' onclick='getValue();'>" + arrayItem + "</span>";
        tagArray[index] = spanObj.toString();
        document.getElementById("tagLinks").innerText = "";
        $("#tagLinks").append(tagArray.join(", "));
        $('#tagLinks').css('cursor','pointer');

    }
  function getValue() {        

    var value = document.getElementById('tagInput').value;
    var newValues = document.getElementsByClassName('clickable');

            for(var i=0; i < newValues.length; i++) {
               document.getElementById('tagInput').value =  newValues[i].innerHTML;     
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the onclick and you are using jQuery so use it.

```
$("#tagLinks").on("click", "span.clickable", function() {
    $('#tagInput').val(this.innerHTML); 
});
```

Comment: One quick follow up question - to get the form to submit on the click I added     

$("#tagLinks").on("click", "span.clickable", function() {
    $('#tagInput').val(this.innerHTML); 
 **   $("form#tag_search-form").submit();  **

});
But it is not running the search and I am not getting an error. Is there something here that I am doing wrong?

Comment: without knowing what the form is...mayeb `$("form#tag_search-form")[0].submit();`

Comment: `<form  id="tag_search_form" name="catcustomcontentform74887" method="post"onsubmit="return checkWholeForm74887(this)" action="/Default.aspx?CCID=24758&amp;FID=345024&amp;ExcludeBoolFalse=True&amp;PageID=15340119">

  <label for="CAT_Custom_16">Tags</label>

  <input id="tagInput" type="text" maxlength="255" value="bibs" name="CAT_Custom_16" id="CAT_Custom_16" />

<input name="tag_search_form" class="cat_button" type="submit" value="Search" />

        </form>`

Comment: well the ids do not match.

Comment: !!! Oh man. THANK YOU SO MUCH. You have saved my sanity. 
Maybe I need glasses.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

as @epascarello said, if you are using jquery, you should use it properly.

anyway, here's a pure javascript answer:

```
function getValue() {        

    var value = document.getElementById('tagInput').value;
    var newValues = document.getElementsByClassName('clickable');

            for(var i=0; i < newValues.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById('tagInput').setAttribute("src","newValues[i].innerHTML");     
            }
    }
```

[Related Docs](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml)